# Getting HttpResponse in Django from Javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, python, django, post

I have a django endpoint:

```
def endpoint(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello!")
```

I call it in JS like this:

```
fetch(baseUrl + "endpoint", {
      method: "POST",
    }).then(function(data) {
        // HOW DO I ACCESS THE "Hello!"?
    });
```

How do i access the hello! in the .then part? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
fetch(baseUrl + "endpoint", {
      method: "POST",
}).then(function(data) {
        data.text().then( text => console.log(text) );
});
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much.